# Click listener for a specific card Recycle View

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview

I need to set a click listener for a specific card, with recycle view and card layout, for each item i need to do a specific stuff, how can i archieve that, i arleady created the custom adapter, but the click is not working yet.

**adapter**

```
package com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.R;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.models.Family;
import com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.models.Photo;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by FilipeCosta on 29/05/2017.
 */

public class FamilyLibraryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FamilyLibraryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    private ArrayList<Family> families;
    private Context context;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onRowClick(int position,String name, int id, View view);
    }

    public FamilyLibraryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Family> families,OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.families = families;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public FamilyLibraryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_library_families_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FamilyLibraryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.name.setText(families.get(i).getName());

        String urlFoto = "http://10.0.2.2:3000" + families.get(i).getPath();


        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(urlFoto)
                .resize(400, 400)
                .into(viewHolder.img);

        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("ENTERED","ENTERED");
                if (listener != null) {
                    Log.d("ENTERED","ENTERED");
                    listener.onRowClick(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),families.get(i).getName(), families.get(i).getId(), v);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return families.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView name;
        private ImageView img;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namePlant);
            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: put your activity class here

Comment: implement onclick listener in viewholder class.

Comment: Doesn't print _Log.d("ENTERED","ENTERED");_ ?

Comment: make sure your layout  activity_library_families_row.. rootView will be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.EventsViewHolder> {

    public static Context context;
    public FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    ArrayList<EventsItem> eventsList;

    public EventsAdapter(ArrayList<EventsItem> arrayList, Context context, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        this.eventsList=arrayList;
        this.context = context;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return eventsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EventsViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {

        final EventsItem  item=eventsList.get(i);
        //String event = item.getEvent_name().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + item.getEvent_name().substring(1).toLowerCase();
        contactViewHolder.b_name.setText(item.getEvent_name());
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(UrlFactory.Image_Url+item.getEvent_image().replace(" ","%20")).into(contactViewHolder.back);
        contactViewHolder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,Events_Details_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("e_id",item.getEvent_id());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        contactViewHolder.desc.setText(""+item.getEvent_description());

            contactViewHolder.date.setText(""+item.getEvent_date());



    }


    @Override
    public EventsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.events_items_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new EventsViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    class EventsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected TextView b_name,desc,date;
        ImageView back;
        CardView card;

        public EventsViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            b_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvevent_name);
            desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tveventdetail);
            date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tveventdate);
            back= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.rleventimage);
            card= (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        }

    /*@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = new BusinessFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_body, fragment)
                .commit();

    }*/

    }
```